# How can I solve $x\left(y^2+z\right)z_x-y\left(x^2+z\right)z_y=\left(x^2-y^2\right)z$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have this right now:

$$x\left(y^2+z\right)z_x-y\left(x^2+z\right)z_y=\left(x^2-y^2\right)z$$

$$\frac{dx}{x\left(y^2+z\right)}=\frac{dy}{-y\left(x^2+z\right)}=\frac{dz}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)z}$$

I get the first first integral like this:

$$\frac{xdx}{x^2\left(y^2+z\right)}=\frac{ydy}{-y^2\left(x^2+z\right)}=\frac{-dz}{-\left(x^2-y^2\right)z}$$

$$\frac{d\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)}{x^2y^2+x^2z}=\frac{d\left(\frac{1}{2}y^2\right)}{-y^2x^2-y^2z}=\frac{d\left(-z\right)}{-x^2z+y^2z}$$

$$\frac{d\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2-z\right)}{0}=ds$$

$$d\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2-z\right)=0$$

$$\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2-z=C$$

$$x^2+y^2-2z=C_1$$

$$\Psi _1\left(x,y,z\right)=x^2+y^2-2z$$

But I am not sure how to get the second first integral

I tried using $z=\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2-C$ when doing:

$$\frac{dx-dy}{x\left(y^2+z\right)+y\left(x^2+z\right)}=\frac{dz}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)z}$$

$$\frac{d\left(x-y\right)}{\frac{1}{2}\left(x+y\right)^3-C\left(x+y\right)}=\frac{dz}{\left(x+y\right)\left(x-y\right)z}$$

$$\frac{2d\left(x-y\right)}{\left(x+y\right)^2-2C}=\frac{dz}{\left(x-y\right)z}$$

$$\frac{2\left(x-y\right)d\left(x-y\right)}{\left(x+y\right)^2-2C}=\frac{dz}{z}$$

Let $w=\left(x-y\right)$ and $C=\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2-z$, then:

$$\frac{2w\:dw}{4z-w^2}=\frac{dz}{z}$$

Then we do for $v=w^2$:

$$\frac{\:dv}{4z-v}=\frac{dz}{z}$$

Which we then solve:

$$\frac{\:dv}{dz}=4-\frac{v}{z}$$

Using $p=\frac{v}{z}$ we get:

$$p+p'z=4-p$$

$$-\frac{1}{2}\frac{dp}{p-2}=\frac{dz}{z}$$

Integrating:

$$-\frac{1}{2}ln\left|p-2\right|+C_2=ln\left|z\right|$$

$$ln\left|\frac{1}{p+2}\right|+C_2=ln\left|z^2\right|$$

$$\frac{C_2}{p+2}=z^2$$

$$C_2=z^2\left(\left(x-y\right)^2+2\right)$$

Is there an easier way to calculate the second first integral? I don't see any mistake in my calculations but still it's very very long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way you found the first identity you can also sum up
$$
ds=\frac{dx/x }{y^2+z}=-\frac{dy/y}{x^2+z}=\frac{dz/z}{x^2-y^2}
$$
to get
$$
ds=\frac{dx/x+dy/y+dz/z}{0}\implies xyz=C_2
$$

Comment: That's a very cool trick, I have to remember this! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Take the first ODE:

$$\frac{dx}{x\left(y^2+z\right)}=\frac{dy}{-y\left(x^2+z\right)}$$
$$y(x^2+z)dx+x(y^2+z)dy=0$$
$$\dfrac 12xy(2xdx+2ydy)+z(ydx+xdy)=0$$
$$\dfrac 12xy(dx^2+dy^2)+z(ydx+xdy)=0$$
$$\dfrac 12xyd(x^2+y^2)+zd(xy)=0$$
And eliminate the $z$ variable since you have:
$$x^2+y^2-2z=C_1$$
$$z=\dfrac {x^2+y^2-C_1}2$$
The ODE becomes separable.
$$xyd(x^2+y^2)+( {x^2+y^2-C_1})d(xy)=0$$
After integration we get:
$$\ln (x^2+y^2-C_1)+\ln (xy)=C$$
$$\ln (2z)+\ln (xy)=C$$
$$\boxed {zxy=C_2}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122881/discussion-on-answer-by-aryadeva-how-can-i-solve-x-lefty2z-rightz-x-y-left).